# Wordpress Custom posts with Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I saw some themes have different sections like "portfolio", 'Testimonial' etc. These are custom posts, but i need to know how to do them? What is the mechanism? Is it about the Taxonomy? My ideas are not clear, Can any one help? Any link for tutorial will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thorough tutorial from Smashing Magazine

http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/